# vue3 page doesnt scroll until refresh

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue, vue-composition-api

I have a vue3 web app. My issue is that once I try to navigate to a page using `<router-link to ="/Dashboard"/>`

Below is the `Dashboard.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="enquiry">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6" v-for="(p, index) in keyAreas" :key="index">
        <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">
              {{ p.number }}
              <span class="card-title" style="float: right">{{ p.title }}</span>
            </h2>
            <h5 class="card-text">
              Properties for rent
              <span class="card-title" style="float: right; margin-top: -5px">
                <Doughnut
                  :chart-data="updateChartData(p.number, totalPropertiesNumber)"
                  :width="80"
                  :height="80"
                />
              </span>
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { projectDatabase } from "../../firebase/config";
import getUser from "../../composables/getUser";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ArcElement,
  CategoryScale,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale);
export default {
  setup() {
    //to get user info e.g email and display name
    const { user } = getUser();
    const company = ref("");
    const keyAreas = ref([]);

    //all LGAs
    const allLGAs = ref([
      { title: "Abuja", number: 0 },
      { title: "Banana Island", number: 0 },
      { title: "Bluewaters Lagos", number: 0 },
      { title: "Benin City", number: 0 },
      { title: "Eko Atlantic", number: 0 },
    ]);

    //Query Function for Specific Locations
    const filterLocation = (item, query, filter) => {
      if (item[filter] === query) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };

    //reference from firebase for user company
    projectDatabase
      .ref("users")
      .child(user.value.uid)
      .child("company")
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        company.value = snapshot.val();

        //loop through all LGAs array and update dashboard by filtering each LGA for its properties in its field
        allLGAs.value.forEach(function (p) {
          p.number = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
            .map((key) => {
              snapshot.val()[key].id = key;
              return snapshot.val()[key];
            })
            .filter((item) => {
              return filterLocation(item, p.title, "location");
            }).length;
          if (p.number > 0) {
            keyAreas.value.push(p);
          }
        });
      });

    return {
      allLGAs,
      company,
      keyAreas,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

The problem is every time i move to a new page, the page freezes and I have to refresh to see all the items in the v-for loop. This happens to about 3 pages on the web app. Is there a way to solve this?

I have also tried disabling all my browser extensions and things of that nature yet the problem still persists. Could it be because of the size of the array being loaded in the v-for?

Comment: Your code snippet was a mess with quite some things unused + errors + poor formatting. Btw, you still have a missing `loading` declaration as of right now. I recommend that you use ESlint to fix all of those errors first. Then, you check with your Vue devtools what is not working here. Check also for some errors in your console, you should get a clear indication of what is not working since ESlint is already able to find those itself. Next time, please also put more effort into providing only the relevant parts of it + format/highlight it with a bit more polish.

Comment: Thank you @kissu that was my bad with the formatting. Regarding errors in the console- I have none which is what is concerning

Comment: ESlint is complaining about `loading`. Check that one if you don't know where to start. Vue devtools too. Also, what about "scrollbar" tag here?

Comment: I edited the question to remove the clumsy residual declarations such as loading and downloaded vue devtools- still no idea of what the issue is

Comment: I realised the issue: `overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;` is being added to my body element when i navigate to specific pages. Any idea how that happens?

Comment: Probably something added by one of the packages you're using. Check for any UI packages or CSS frameworks.

Comment: For anyone who has this issue - @kissu's comment is correct. Bootstrap v5 has a class called "offcanvas" that adds the overflow properties to your body. You need to enable scrolling to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP solved his issue by finding out that Bootstrap v5 adds a class called `offcanvas` with

```css
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Enabling the scrolling makes it functional again.